# css transition on preudo element does not work

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a button "play" on video box, but transition on `:before` element does not work.

what am I doing wrong?

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  transition:1s;
}
div:before:hover{
  transition:1s;
}

div:hover:before{
  content:"";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0094d9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 45%;
  top: 40%;
  transition: 1s;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add all the css in `:before` element and instead of `hover`

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  transition:1s;
}
div:before{
  content:"";
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0094d9;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
}
div:hover:before{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Moving the styling to the `:before` would help solve this problem. Then you could add the transition on `:before` and transition the `border-color` property:

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
}

div:before {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 9999;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 50px 0 50px 86.6px;
  border-color: transparent;
  transition: all 1s linear;
}

div:hover:before{
  border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0094d9;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f6sw2sok/2/) Example.

Answer (score 0):

I found you might did some mistake here is the solution.

```css
div{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: #000;
  position: relative;
  transition:1s;
}
div:hover:before{
  transition:1s;
opacity:1;
}

div:before{
content: "";
border-style: solid;
border-width: 30px 0 30px 66.6px;
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #0094d9;
position: absolute;
z-index: 9999;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transition: 1s;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```